# A jsp page with two separate forms

Tags: java, forms, jsp

I want an index page with two separate forms. Individually it works, but they don't work together.
My files is this:

IndexController.java:

```
@Controller
public class indexController {
@Autowired
UserService userService;
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewLogin(Model model) {
    Admin adminForm = new Admin();
    Graph chartGraph = new Graph();
    model.addAttribute("adminForm", adminForm); 
    model.addAttribute("chartGraph", chartGraph);
    return "index";
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processIn(@ModelAttribute("adminForm") Admin admin, 
        Model model) {              
    System.out.println("adminname: " + admin.getUsername());
    System.out.println("password: " + admin.getPassword());     
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/graph", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processIn(@ModelAttribute("chartGraph") Graph graph, 
        Model model) {              
    System.out.println("height: " + graph.getAltezza());
    System.out.println("weight: " + graph.getLarghezza());              
    return "index";
    }
}
```

index.jsp 
   [image]

What is wrong?
If you need other file ask me. Thanks.

Comment: Any error/exception you see?

Comment: The error is on:<form:input path="altezza" /> if I submit the form adminForm and on <form:input path="username" /> if submit the form chartGraph.

Comment: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'adminForm' available as request attribute

Comment: I solved it by changing the controller: Leaving only one POST method and adding another model attribute it                                                     <code> @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String processIn(@ModelAttribute("adminForm") Admin admin, @ModelAttribute("chartGraph") Graph graph,
   Model model) {  </code>